# Underline overfull \hbox

Tags: warnings, underline, overfull

I am getting the following `Overfull \hbox (0.10945pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--13`. How could I prevent this?

I am using `\,` inside `\dotuline` because I want to use a little bit longer dotted underline.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[dot]{dashundergaps}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

Lorem \dotuline{\,\,LoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLoremLorem LoremLoremLoremLoremLorem\,\,} Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, noheadfoot]{geometry}
\hyphenation{Lor-em}
\usepackage[dot]{dashundergaps}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

Lorem \dotuline{\,\,Lor\-emLor\-emLor\-emLor\-emLor\-emLor\-emLor\-em} Lor\-em Lor\-emLor\-emLor\-emLor\-emLor\-emLor\-em Lor\-em Lor\-em Lor\-em Lor\-em Lor\-em Lor\-em Lor\-em Lor\-em Lor\-em Lor\-em Lor\-em Lor\-em

\end{document}
```

In this case I am getting the following `Overfull \hbox (20.50162pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--14`

Comment: why do you have `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` as you are not setting `\parskip` you make it very difficult to distinguish paragraphs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle cuz I do not want indention. After each paragraph I use ˛`\vskip 1cm`

Comment: `\newcommand{\newpara}{\vskip 1cm}` I think this is better looking, or is there a better way?

Comment: do not mark each paragraph space. the paragraph layout is a global property of the document. Just use  a blank line to end a paragraph, add `\usepackage{parskip}` and paragraphs will be marked with vertical space rather than indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your string of Lorems simply stretches past the line limit, and TeX can't find a good place to end the line (before the Lorem would add too much space, and inserting the break afterward, which it does, overfills the hbox). (This is unrelated to your `\dotuline`).

Try locating which "Lorem" TeX inserts a line break after, and insert a discretionary hyphen (`\-`) in it somewhere to tell TeX to allow a break there (eg `Lor\-em`).

You could also add `\hyphenation{Lor-em}` to your preamble to let TeX know that whenever it encounters a Lorem it needs to break up, it can insert a discretionary hyphen between the r and e.

Comment: I have just added an **UPDATE** to my question. As you can see I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @mala97 now you have no spaces between many of your "Lor\-em"s, which still leads to the same issue (you have unbreakable "emLor"s). **Also**, instead of doing many `Lor\-em`s, perhaps just put `\hyphenation{Lor-em}` in your preamble.